# VMware ESXi6.5u1 client support

Tags: vmware, virtualization, vsphere, esxi

I know VMware has provided the support for **HTML5 based client** to manage the VMware host.
We want to use vSphere client6.0 to manage VMware ESxi 6.5u1.

I have one vSphere client with version 6.0 and two ESXi server with version6.5 and 6.5u1.

I have observed the below behavior of vSphere client and ESXi server.

- **I am able to access VMware 6.5 with vSphere client6.0**
- **I am unable to access ESxi6.5u1 with vSphere client6.0** . It give me options for run installer or Save installer.

Can you please reply on my below queries?

- if a can open ESXi6.5 with vSphere client6.0 then why i cannot open ESXi 6.5u1??
- Where VMware has documented the compatibility of vSphere client with ESXi server?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compatibility matrix for the vSphere thick client is located here: http://partnerweb.vmware.com/comp_guide2/sim/interop_matrix.php#interop&24=&1=

I believe the thick client being operational with 6.5 ESXi hosts was a bug, and it was resolved in 6.5U1.

Also, be aware that the thick client has been deprecated and will no longer be available on future versions of vSphere: https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2016/05/goodbye-vsphere-client-for-windows-c-hello-html5.html